# what is meant by NIC manufacturers

Tags: networking, network-adapter

i searched cannot find the meaning

Comment: When I search *nic manufacturer* via Google, two of the results on the first page contain "network card", another one is the NIC Wikipedia article. Where did you search again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIC is short for Network Interface Card, or more simply known as a Network Card. It is the interface that has the LAN port on your computer. It is the port you plug the ethernet cable into.
It can be a PCMCIA, PCI, USB, or just built onto the motherboard. The manufacturer is usually the company that makes the card, but most importantly is the chip that the card uses, as any drivers needed for these devices are determined by the chip.